# Add footer without Master page modification in SharePoint (Office 365)

Tags: office-365, master-page, footer

Are there any approaches to add a sticky footer to all pages in SP site without Master Page modifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it by JavaScript injection. Microsoft recommends using this technique rather than creating / modifying master pages for UI.
You can find more information on web:

[Customize your SharePoint site UI by using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/customize-your-sharepoint-site-ui-by-using-javascript?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[JavaScript injection in SharePoint Online - Office 365 Developer Patterns and Practices](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/JavaScript-injection-in-SharePoint-Online-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices)

Answer (score 4):

PnP has a great example on adding Header , breadcrumb and footer on all pages without modifying the Masterpage.

It is basically as SharePoint hosted-app that can be deployed on the site collection. After you add and install the app, it will add a user custom action which will inject the javascript on the page. In the below image, you need to click on the Add provision button, which will do the needful.

[Core.EmbedJavaScript.HeaderFooter](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Core.EmbedJavaScript.HeaderFooter/Core.EmbedJavaScript.HeaderFooter)

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!